# Jsoup parse response without logging to console

Tags: java, rest, jsoup

I have a tiny problem with Jsoup.
I am using this snippet of code

```
        Response response = getAccount(); // GET Response in HTML format
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(response.body().prettyPrint());
```

And it prints to console all the response, which is very messy, as response is in HTML format. I read that `prettyPeek()` is not logging response, but return value of `prettyPeek()` is not String type but Response, and even if I use `prettyPeek().toString()` my code doesn't work. Please tell me what snippet will work the same way as mine, but without logging to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse HTML into a Document just parse the body:

```
 Document document = Jsoup.parse(response.body());
```

And that's it.
Also do you really need a reponse as a Response object?
You can get the Document by simply calling:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
```

Take a look at these very simple examples to see if there's a better way to do what you're trying to achieve:
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url